# GridViewBuilder is not showing my fetched data

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using a gridview.builder to show my fetched data from firestore. But the builder is not showing my products. I checked out the complete code of firebase fetch and everything is working. Still I am unable to show data using builder. Here is the code. Please help

**main.dart**

```
if (state is SearchScreenDefaultState) {
                return GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                    maxCrossAxisExtent: 2,
                    childAspectRatio: 1 / 1.3,
                  ),
                  itemCount: state.snapshot.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return productCard(
                      product: ProductModel.fromJson(
                          state.snapshot.docs[index].data()),
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
```

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with gridview builder, check the update code once and let me know if this works for you. Please update your code for more information.

```
if (state is SearchScreenDefaultState) {
                return GridView.builder(
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    childAspectRatio: 1 / 1.3,
                  ),
                  itemCount: state.snapshot.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return productCard(
                      product: ProductModel.fromJson(
                          state.snapshot.docs[index].data()),
                    );
                  },
                );
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
```